# jQuery UI slider - setting max option changes value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have created a jQuery UI Slider with a step of 0.01

I set the value using `.slider("value", value)` but have noticed that if I set the `max` option to be certain values (for example `n.31` or `n.33`), this immediately amends the value

What option in the slider is stopping the value remaining unaltered when the max option is set to a certain value?

The values being entered are 2 decimal places, so no rounding is taking place

The following snippet shows 25.33 being set but the value being reset to 25.32 and as a comparison, 25.39 being set with the value remaining as 25.39

```js
 $("#slider1").slider({
   range: "min",
   min: 0,
   max: 100,
   step: 0.01,
   create: function(event, ui) {
     var value = 25.33
     $(this).slider("value", value);
     $(this).slider("option", "max", value);
     
     var sliderValueAfterSet = $(this).slider("value");
     $('#result1').val(sliderValueAfterSet);
   }
 });
 
  $("#slider2").slider({
   range: "min",
   min: 0,
   max: 100,
   step: 0.01,
   create: function(event, ui) {
     var value = 25.39
     $(this).slider("value", value);
     $(this).slider("option", "max", value);
     
     var sliderValueAfterSet = $(this).slider("value");
     $('#result2').val(sliderValueAfterSet);
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"
  integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<div id="slider1"></div>
<input type="text" id="result1">

<div id="slider2"></div>
<input type="text" id="result2">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `0.001` to help it round the right way. There appears to be some math being applied that is causing it to drop to `25.32`.

```js
$("#slider1").slider({
  range: "min",
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  step: 0.01,
  create: function(event, ui) {
    // Adding 0.001 to help rounding in Max
    var value = 25.331
    $(this).slider("option", "max", value);
    $(this).slider("value", value);

    var sliderValueAfterSet = $(this).slider("value");
    $('#result1').val(sliderValueAfterSet);
  }
});

$("#slider2").slider({
  range: "min",
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  step: 0.01,
  create: function(event, ui) {
    var value = 25.39
    $(this).slider("value", value);
    $(this).slider("option", "max", value);

    var sliderValueAfterSet = $(this).slider("value");
    $('#result2').val(sliderValueAfterSet);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="slider1"></div>
<input type="text" id="result1">

<div id="slider2"></div>
<input type="text" id="result2">
```

Alternately, you can do integer math versus float and then divide down.

```js
$("#slider1").slider({
  range: "min",
  min: 0,
  max: 10000,
  step: 1,
  create: function(event, ui) {
    var value = 2533
    $(this).slider("option", "max", value);
    $(this).slider("value", value);

    var sliderValueAfterSet = $(this).slider("value");
    $('#result1').val(sliderValueAfterSet / 100);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" integrity="sha256-T0Vest3yCU7pafRw9r+settMBX6JkKN06dqBnpQ8d30=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="slider1"></div>
<input type="text" id="result1">
```